# Large number division in bash returns wrong result

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash

I'm trying to convert a very large number of bytes into gigabytes.

`echo $(( 41003021288998461440 / 1073741824 ))`

This returns 3827300985.  That is incorrect.  The correct answer would be 38187039354.  11 digits versus 10.

Using different 'scale = 30' or piping through bc doesn't change the answer.  What am I doing wrong?

As an alternative I tried this:

`awk -v var1=41003021288998461440 -v var2=1073741824 'BEGIN { print ( var1 / var2 ) }' OFMT='%25g'`

Which returns "3.8187e+10", which seems to be numerically correct, but I then can't figure out how not to get in scientific notation.  Printf "%12d" isn't helping because it can't seem to handle the division in a passed parameter.

I suspect fixing the awk scientific notation issue would probably be easier, but I'd still like to know why the long division with echo just returns a completely wrong result.  That's very concerning, and since I do calculations in that way frequently, I'd like to know what I need to do to get echo to calculate accurately.

I also know that I fixed the problem once before... but I lost how I did it and can't recall now, sigh.

Comment: In the awk version, `printf "%12f", ( var1 / var2 )` gives me `38187039353.883324`, and `%12d` gives `38187039353`

Comment: I think your awk `OFMT` assignment fails because (at least in GNU awk) it only takes effect after the `BEGIN` block is executed: either use `-v OFMT='%d'` or add it inside the block `BEGIN { OFMT="%d"; print ( var1 / var2 )}`. See [Assigning Variables on the Command Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Assignment-Options).

Comment: ... in older versions of GAWK, you may also need to enable arbitrary precision support explicitly using the `-M` or `--bignum` options

Answer (score 1):

[Bash integers](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) are not arbitrary precision:

> Evaluation is done in fixed-width integers with no check for overflow,
> though division by 0 is trapped and flagged as an error.

A likely upper limit in modern systems would be 2^63 for signed integers:

```
$ echo $(( 2**63 - 1 ))
9223372036854775807
$ echo $(( 2**63 ))
-9223372036854775808
$ echo $(( 2**62 ))
4611686018427387904
```

Your number is waaaay too large (~4x) for that. If you want to do random arbitrary precision arithmetic interactively, use Python:

```
>>> 41003021288998461440 / 1073741824
38187039353.88332
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it best to use dc for this:

```
V=$(echo "8 k 41003021288998461440 1073741824 / p" | dc)
echo $V
```

This sets the precision to 8, divides the next two values and then pops it off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Finally reconstructed how to do make it calculate accurately.  And yes, it did involve using 'scale'.

`BYTECOUNT=$(echo "scale=0; (( $BYTECOUNT / 1073741824 )) " | bc )`

The above worked (with BYTECOUNT previously set to the grossly large initial number). Odd that scale=0 is necessary since I believe that is supposed to be the default, but it does appear to be necessary to make it explicit in order to get the calculation to come out correctly.